# Joomla installation prevention with a mysql warning

Tags: mysql, joomla

I seem to keep encountering an installation issue for installing Joomla on Linux. Although without Joomla I can still independently create/modify sql queries accessing mariadb with `mysql -u root -p` then starting lampp with `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start` and website building as soon as I `xdg-open /opt/lampp/htdocs`, I am still unable to figure out how to by pass the Warning I keep getting when I try to install Joomla by creating that Admin account installation process.

The warning message I keep getting is: `The installer was not able to connect to the MySQL. Please make sure MySQL is running and introduce a valid password to connect to the MySQL server.

I was assuming the MYSQL was automatically running since I am able to create sql fields and input them from mariadb... and also the fact that when I run: `mysqladmin -u root -p status` because I still see Uptime, but I do not think that is the case.. so I am not really sure...

Comment: Which linux distro are you using ? try to restart apache server, If you're using Red hat/ Arch based system just run mysqld in CLI then try to install Joomla.

Comment: My operating system is Arch Linux Gnome x86_64